# Is there any limitations for runs per users in Azure ML experiments?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk, azure-python-sdk, azuremlsdk

I and my team members are working on a machine learning project through the **Azure ML** portal.
We have created a specific *experiment* in our *workspace* in Azure ML and are submitting our Python script *runs* from our local or remote machines in this experiment.

Although I'm collaborating with my colleagues, most of the runs in this specific experiment are submitted by me.

Recently, I have faced a problem with experiment submissions.
The problem is that after some number of experiments created by me, I cannot add any other runs to this experiment, but my colleagues can!!!

Unfortunately, the Azure ML portal does not show any clear error message for this problem. It continues submitting the run till a *timeout* exception occurs!

As a temporary solution, I've just changed the name of the experiment and I could conquer this problem.

This solution helped me to submit my run on **Azure ML** but it didn’t satisfy me because we want to collect all related runs under a specific experiment. On the other hand creating multiple number of experiments for each run is overwhelming!

What I know is that there are some service limits for the number of runs in a workspace on this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/resource-limits-quotas-capacity). I am sure that the number of runs in our workspace has not reached to the 10 millions, because I can created new runs under new experiments dashboard. But I don’t know anything about the limitations on the number of runs in a specific experiment or even any limitations for the number of runs per users in a specific experiment.
I couldn't find any clear document explaining this fact.

Is there anyone who can help me for this issue?